# Changing CSS display block using jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attaching my jsfiddle demo where I have a simple div tag with display set as none at first. On button click I want the display to be set as block so it is visible. I been trying to figure this out for the longest time and I cannot see what am I doing wrong. Help appreciated!

[Here is my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5bk090gs/14/)

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#go').click(function() {
         $("#warningMessage").css("display", "block");
     });
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="go" href="#" >Show text</a>

<div id = "warningMessage" class="testClass" style="display: none;">
    <p id="warningMsg" > Status change action would not be saved until you click Save button. </p>
<div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Include jquery in the fiddle

Comment: Always check to the console for errors. That would have told you $ was undefined.

Comment: Ok please close this question. I found the root cause to my issue as Draco stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you didn't include jQuery.  Your code works fine.

Comment: thanks Draco for the helpful answer. Looks like everyone else is ready to beat me up lol

Comment: Rep's just a number, don't take it personally.  Learn from your mistakes: use the console, search SO more carefully, explain your problem to a rubber duck.